# File attachment value is not getting saved in database

Tags: database, magento-2.1.3

I have created a **custom form**, in which I have given an option to upload a **file**. But something is going wrong, I an unable to locate where I am going wrong.

All other fields like - Name, number, email, postcode are getting saved in database but **attachment field** is not. Here is my code.

Controller - Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Magecoder\Quote\Controller\Contact;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator as FormKeyValidator;

class Save extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
     */
    protected $_formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var \Magecoder\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $quoteModel;

    /**
     * @param Context          $context
     * @param Session          $customerSession
     * @param FormKeyValidator $formKeyValidator
     * @param SaveProduct      $saveProduct
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magecoder\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        FormKeyValidator $formKeyValidator) {
        $this->_formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->quoteModel = $quote;
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }
    /**
     * seller product save action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            try {
                $storeId = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
                //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams()); die('okkk');
                $quoteRequestSent = $this->quoteModel->saveQuoteRequest($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());


 $attachment = 'file';
            if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                try {           

                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($attachment);
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf','txt','jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts' . DS ;
                    if(!is_dir($path)){
                        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                    }
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['contacts'] );             
                    $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();


                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $error = true;
                }
                echo $newFilename;
            }

                if (!$quoteRequestSent) { 
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                            __('Unable to send request! Please try again..')
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                            __('Request sent successffully!')
                    );
                }
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                                '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());

                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                                '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
                );
            }
        } else {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                            '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my view page request.phtml -

```
<div class="wk-mp-design">
    <fieldset class="fieldset info wk-mp-fieldset">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span><?php echo __('Quote Request') ?></span>
        </legend>
  <form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('quote/contact/save', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="quote-request" data-form="quote-request" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Full Name') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" title="Full Name" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Street Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="street_address" name="street_address" title="Street Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Suburb') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="district" name="district" title="Suburb" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Post Code') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="post_code" name="post_code" title="Post Code" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" title="Phone Number" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label"><?php echo __('Email Address') ?>:</label>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Email Address" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <?php echo __("Please attach any photo's that will help describe your job.(Max 5 images/3Mb of data. JPGS Only)") ?>
                <div class="control">
                        <input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment"  title="Attachment" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field required">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="input-text" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" type="submit" id="submit-btn">
                <span><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></span>
            </button>
              <button class="button wk-mp-btn" title="<?php echo __('Reset') ?>" >
                <span><span><?php echo __('Reset') ?></span></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#quote-request": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is saving post values

```
$quoteRequestSent = $this->quoteModel->saveQuoteRequest($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
```

but in that post value have no file name you have to use below code to save file name

```
$postdata = array();
$postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
$postdata['file_field_db_name'] = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
 $quoteRequestSent = $this->quoteModel->saveQuoteRequest($postdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes : You have to add your new file name in Database and for that you have to add that file name along with the post data. Right now you are just saving post data not new uploaded file.

```
public function execute()
    {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        try {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams()); die('okkk');
            //$quoteRequestSent = $this->quoteModel->saveQuoteRequest($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); //added code line


        $attachment = 'file';
        if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
            try {           

                $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', array('fileId' => 'attachment'));
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf','txt','jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                //$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts' . DS ;
                //if(!is_dir($path)){
                  //  mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                //}
                //$uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['contacts'] );  
                        $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('contacts'));          
                $newFilename = $result['file'];//$uploader->getUploadedFileName();
            $data['image_field_name'] = $newFilename;  //added code line

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = true;
            }
            //echo $newFilename;
        }
        $quoteRequestSent = $this->quoteModel->saveQuoteRequest($data);  //added code line

            if (!$quoteRequestSent) { 
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('Unable to send request! Please try again..')
                );
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                        __('Request sent successffully!')
                );
            }
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                            '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());

            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                            '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
            );
        }
    } else {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                        '*/*/request', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
        );
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am using the above code, getting error - Fatal error: Class 'Magecoder\Quote\Controller\Contact\Varien_File_Uploader' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mag2.1.3/app/code/Magecoder/Quote/Controller/Contact/Save.php on line 57

Comment: @Khushbu_sipl, Try updated answer.

Comment: Its again giving the same error - Fatal error: Class 'Magecoder\Quote\Controller\Contact\Varien_File_Uploader' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mag2.1.3/app/code/Magecoder/Quote/Controller/Contact/Save.php on line 57

Comment: u mean above code is for mag1x, but I want code for mag2x

Comment: But now, when I am using ur code facing this - Fatal error: Class 'Magecoder\Quote\Controller\Contact\DirectoryList' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mag2.1.3/app/code/Magecoder/Quote/Controller/Contact/Save.php on line 62

Comment: $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

Comment: @Khushbu_sipl, add this line `use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;` before class declaration and do compile again

Comment: Why i am getting this :(       -- Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::getDirectoryRead() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mag2.1.3/app/code/Magecoder/Quote/Controller/Contact/Save.php on line 59